# AngularJS: Getting $scope is not defined error when I already have $scope declared

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying a few different configurations, but I keep getting a `$scope is not defined error` with my AngularJS file, despite having it defined in the controller.

I'm trying to get both the `$scope.idStore` and `$scope.patientTime` working in the controller section at the bottom. These functions pull data from input boxes with a certain ID. They are then stored as a `patientID` variable. `patientTime` concatenates this ID with an additional timestamp, then generates an alert message.

Testing shows that I get the error when trying to read the `idStore` or `patientTime`

Below is the main AngularJS code:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
//generate JSON-based list for menu links
    var AppCtrl;
    AppCtrl = function () {
        function AppCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.list = [
                {
                    label: 'Main Menu',
                    icon: 'fa fa-home fa-fw 4x',
                    link: '#/appLaunch',
                    move: function() {
                                 console.log("HOME");
                            }
                },
                {
                    label: 'Patient',
                    icon: 'fa fa-user fa-fw 4x',
                    link: '#/pCredential',
                    move: function(){
                        console.log("PATIENT");
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'Technician',
                    icon: 'fa fa-user-md fa-fw 4x',
                    link: '#/tLogin',
                    move: function(){
                        console.log("TECHNICIAN");
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'Administrator',
                    icon: 'fa fa-cogs fa-fw 4x',
                    link: '#/aLogin',
                    move: function(){
                        console.log("ADMINISTRATOR");
                    }
                }
            ];
        }
        return AppCtrl;
    }();
// Declare app level module which depends on views and components
angular.module('careApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngMaterial',
  'ngAria',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngMaterialDatePicker',
  'careApp.appLaunch',
  'careApp.pCredential',
  'careApp.dialog1',
  'careApp.pSurvey',
  'careApp.pTheme',
  'careApp.pThanks',
  'careApp.tLogin',
  'careApp.tMain',
  'careApp.aLogin'
])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    //if given invalid partial, go back to appLaunch.html
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/appLaunch'});
}])

.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', AppCtrl]);
      //declare empty patientID to be accessed by functions
      var patientID = '';

      //grab relevant data from input and add it to patientID
      $scope.idStore = function() {
        var patientFirstInitial = document.getElementById('patientFirstInitial');
        var patientLastName = document.getElementById('patientLastName');
        var aptDate = document.getElementById('aptDate');
        var aptTime = document.getElementById('aptTime');
        //store patientID as global variable
        patientID = patientFirstInitial + patientLastName + aptDate + aptTime;
        console.log('Registered ' + patientID);
      }

      //on time selection, concat to patientID, then throw alert
      $scope.patientTime = function(){
        //concats selected theme to patient ID, then sends to database
        var patientTheme = document.getElementById('');
        patientID += patientTheme;
        alert('Patient ' + patientID + ' has been registered.');
      }
}());
```

My suspicion is centered on how I have this AngularJS file set up. **Was this done incorrectly?**

Comment: `var AppCtrl;` is declared within the scope of your declaration function and not globably

Comment: In addition to what @Dalorzo said, you've wrapped the `AppCtrl` definition in an IIFE and I imagine that you should also be experiencing some troubles with the scope of `AppCtrl` since your're referencing it inside your `angular.controller` definition which is outside the IIFE. You should also be mindful of your `'use strict';` placement since that also affects how it is enforced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had `AppCtrl` defined twice in function, Also you are messed up with IIFE closing brackets. It should not be in between after `AppCtrl` code. It should be there to end.

**Code**

```
(function() {
    AppCtrl = function($scope) {
        //why don't have it simple like this
        //inner code will be as is
    };
      // Declare app level module which depends on views and components
    angular.module('careApp', [
      //many dependecies
    ])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      //if given invalid partial, go back to appLaunch.html
      $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/appLaunch'
      });
    }])

    .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', AppCtrl]);
    //code as is
})();
```

---

`$scope is undefined` error has occured because, you had

```
AppCtrl = function () {
```

hich is AppCtrl function, without having `$scope` dependency. And inside that function you are asking for `$scope` value without injecting it here like `function AppCtrl($scope) {`

while explaining 2nd part of answer assuming that you had correct, variable references.

Comment: IIFE syntax is still messed up at very  end of OP code. I think OP intended to wrap all of this in one IIFE otherwise makes no sense doing `window.AppCtrl = AppCtrl;`

Comment: @charlietfl good eyes.. thanks mate for heads up.. :-) edited mine answer

Comment: Thanks for the help! This appears to have resolved my issue.